# Simplification of successive 'if' statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a series of `if` statements, as shown below:

```
if (board[x+1][y]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x][y+1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x-1][y]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x][y-1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x+1][y+1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x+1][y-1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x-1][y+1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
if (board[x-1][y-1]==true) {
    ar+=1;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify/condense these statements with Java?

Comment: `== true` is redundant. You do not need it.

Comment: Perhaps you are searching for the `switch` statement? Also, are you writing battleship?

Comment: I considered the `switch` statement, but that's only if you're comparing one variable, so I didn't see how I could apply that here. Also, this code is for a visual Conway's Game of Life simulation, but good guess!

Comment: @HanletEscaño nope, more than one could be true in which case more than one should be added

Comment: @HanletEscaño That wouldn't work. `ar` needs to increment for **each** time one is `true`. Notice that they aren't `else if` statements.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev Can you add boolean values in Java as though they were integers?  I thought you can't.

Comment: I think your question would be better in [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: This must be a duplicate of something, right? *Right?*

Comment: @SonerGönül In it's current form, it would be closed for lacking context. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The code posted here is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at the author's intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: @Mast Fair enough :)

Comment: I'd consider separating checking the board contents from enumerating the neighbours.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Simply loop around the position that you care about. Skipping the center of the "box".

Tip: You access a 2D array by row **then** column, or `[y][x]` (at least, that's how you'd translate the board from looking at the code).

```
// int x, y;  // position to look around 
for (int xDiff = -1; xDiff <= 1; xDiff++) {
    for (int yDiff = -1; yDiff <= 1; yDiff++) {
        if (xDiff == 0 && yDiff == 0) continue;
        if (board[y+yDiff][x+xDiff]) { 
            ar += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Beware - Out of bounds exception is not handled

Comment: As long as they are consistent about `[x][y]` or `[y][x]`, there's really no difference.

Comment: True, but clear intention is always good.

Comment: Excellent idea! I appreciate your promptness is responding!

Comment: I did this a few time, it even let me expand by changing the 1 in the for loop with a variable called radius.

Comment: @the_lotus Sure. This could be expanded to `radius` to `-radius`, but the question seemed to be asking about direct neighbors to cell `[x][y]`

Comment: @cricket_007 your answer was perfect, I just wanted to add something for other people that sees it.

Comment: @the_lotus Gotcha. It would need more work to count all cells between a `radius > 1` and the center, obviously, though.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Please only comment for questions/comments related to *this post*

Answer (score 13):

The following would be a more visual equivalent, easily extensible to other shapes of the area of interest. Note ternary operators, `?:` which are necessary in Java to convert bools to ints.

```
ar += (board[x-1][y-1]?1:0) + (board[x-1][y]?1:0) + (board[x-1][y+1]?1:0);
ar += (board[x+0][y-1]?1:0) +                       (board[x+0][y+1]?1:0);
ar += (board[x+1][y-1]?1:0) + (board[x+1][y]?1:0) + (board[x+1][y+1]?1:0);
```

Comment: although this ain't, arguably, the best way to do it (can't extrapolate it easily to bigger board sizes, can be suboptimal in languages where ternaries are evaluated at runtime exclusively etc.), +1 for the freshness of the very idea of grouping them visually depending on coords.

Comment: Maybe change to a helper function `get(board, x-1, y-1)` so that you don't need to repeat the ternary, and also can add bounds checking easily.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answers you already have, you can also use enhanced for loops (and re-use the range as it is the same for both).

```
int[] range = { -1, 0, 1 };
for (int i : range) {
  for (int j : range) {
    if ((i != 0 || j != 0) && board[i][j])  { 
      ar++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the board[i][j] truth test. I added it in an edit.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Comment: I always used a for-loop from -1 to 1, never thought about that one... this is cleaner!

Answer (score 8):

This code should give the same result (probably you want to check that you are always in the bounds of the matrix

```
for(int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
   for(int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
        if((i != 0 || j != 0) && board[x+i][y+j]) {
           ar++;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify as follows as well :

```
for(int i = x-1;i<=x+1;i++) {
    for(int j=y-1;j<=y+1;j++) { 
        if(i==x && j==y) continue;
        if (board[i][j]) {
           ar+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be shortened further to a single line: `for (int i=x-1;i<=x+1;i++) for (int j=y-1;j<=y+1;j++) if ((i!=x || j!=y) && board[i][j]) ar+=1;`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're testing surrounding squares apart from (x, y) itself. I'd use a loop to maintain a counter, with extra step to exclude the (x, y) centre cell.

```
for (int xTest = x - 1; xTest <= x + 1; xTest++) {
    for (int yTest = y - 1; yTest <= y + 1; yTest++) {
        if (xTest == x && yTest == y) {
            continue;
        }
        if (board[xTest][yTest]) {
            ar += 1;
        }
    }           
}
```

Also, note the == true is unnecessary. Boolean statements are first class citizens in Java.