# ArrayIndedOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java

I have a problem with my loop, it must be a basic fix but i cant seem to fix this issue, this is a 2D array that i am checking the neighbours of a grid for , now

if randomGrid [rows -1] and [col] == 1 , this means the cell that is on the left of the current cell on the x Axis

```
for(int rows = 0 ; rows < randomGrid.length ; ++rows){
        for(int cols = 0 ; cols < randomGrid.length ; ++cols){

            //all 8 neighbours 
             if(randomGrid[rows-1][cols] == 1){
                 neighbours++;
             }
             if(randomGrid[rows-1][cols-1] == 1){
                 neighbours++;
             }
```

error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at Control.count(Control.java:196)
 at Control.main(Control.java:247)
```

Comment: Don't start `rows` or `cols` at `0` if you're going to use `rows-1` and/or `cols-1`.

Comment: Tip: `cols < randomGrid[rows].length`

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837371/simplification-of-successive-if-statements-in-java/40837409#40837409

Answer (score 0):

```
randomGrid[rows-1][cols]
```

is -1 when row is zero

So you need to make that lines

```
randomGrid[rows][cols]
```

Comment: Actually, `int rows = 1` would make more sense than this

Comment: @cricket_007 I think s/he has `row+1` too inside for loop. The code is not finished, so s/he just need to be careful in either case. But I agree, it might be easier for the OP.